# How do I add an iframe whitelist to OS X Server 3.1.1

Tags: osx-server, server.app

I can't seem to be able to find how to add a whitelist to the Wiki Server on OS X Server 3.1.1 the collabd service.

The information is missing from the documentation at

http://help.apple.com/wikiuser/mac/4.0/

neither at:

https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/3.1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix to this problem --
Instead of changing the white list file in /Library/Server/Wiki/Config you have to change the whitelist.plist.default fine in the Server.app bundle (/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/private/etc/collabd/whitelist.plist.default). I did and all works well, even after restart.

Hope that helps!

-Matt

From over on https://discussions.apple.com/message/25866041#25866041#25866041